# JetBrains Rider - is there an easy way to generate the XML documentation file?

Tags: c#, build, rider, xml-documentation

VS has a checkbox that just builds the XML documentation file from C#.  I couldn't find anything like this in JetBrains Rider's build settings.  What's the easiest way to do this?

[image: documentation comments]

[image: rider example]

[image: vs example]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to open Solution Explorer, choose the appropriate project, go to project properties and enable generating for the specific project configuration (or all of them):

[image: How to find xml doc settings]

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't coming up in the other options menu's.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed =) How you tried to find it? Via search in settings?

Comment: Yeah, I had tried searching for a few queries and gave up after 10-15 minutes.  Maybe I was searching the wrong terms though.  Would be great if it came up in the search box.

Answer (score 1):

Rider has public Youtrack (tool to track issues). For the future I recommend to check there before posting here, as usually it has been raised there.

Here is a link to the issue about XML documentation:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-7433?_ga=2.64467503.1034831768.1641148468-999122819.1639050883

Workaround to achieve it is to add to the .csproj file

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\PowerBiApiService.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, I posted a comment there as suggested.  That workaround is from 2017, hoping there has been more traction since then.

Comment: You are right this one is quite out-of-date it seems that this now the up-to-date feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-17038?_ga=2.67427473.1034831768.1641148468-999122819.1639050883. But still not implemented as of now